# Looking for a startswith equivalent for integers in panda

Tags: python, pandas

I have an integer column. all rows have 9 digits, the first either starts with 5 or 7. i am trying to filter for ones that only start with 7. is there a .str.startswith equivalent for integer dtypes? or do i need to convert to string and back to integer?

```
df["Case #"].str.startswith(7)
```

Comment: If you care about formatting like this, it probably shouldn't be a number in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're all 9 digits, you can just use numeric comparisons:

```py
(df["Case #"].between(700000000, 799999999) 
 |  df["Case #"].between(500000000, 599999999))
```

Comment: The '`or`' does not work with pandas as you're applying a condition on a vector, you need `|` wrapped inside parenthesis. Also the (a < series < b) comparison should be `series.between(a, b, inclusive=True)` to avoid the same issue.

Comment: @cs95 I'm not a pandas programmer -- if you could edit the answer to show the correct syntax, that would be great. Or you could post a correct answer and I'll delete.

Comment: Fixed, but I do quite like the idea of sticking to arithmetic checks, since string operations are generally slower than arithmetic with pandas.

Comment: @cs95 But I still think they probably shouldn't be using numbers. It's like using numbers for credit cards, phone numbers, account numbers, zip codes, etc. Even though they contain digits, they're not really numbers.

Comment: Yeah, I don't recommend it either especially if missing data is involved. On pandas >= 1.0 though NA values have better interoperability with ints so it isn't as big a deal, might even be preferred because of the potential performance gain working with numerics.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to skin a cat here:

```
# fake
np.random.seed([3, 14])
s = pd.Series((np.random.choice(8, 10) + 1) * 1e8, name='Case', dtype='int')
s      

0    100000000
1    800000000
2    500000000
3    200000000
4    800000000
5    500000000
6    400000000
7    500000000
8    600000000
9    700000000
Name: Case, dtype: int64
```

Using arithmetic with `isin` check, since all numbers have the same digits:

```
# (df['case'] // 1e8).astype(int).isin([5, 7]) 
(s // 1e8).astype(int).isin([5, 7]) 

0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7     True
8    False
9     True
Name: Case, dtype: bool
```

---

This is *much* slower. Convert to string and check the first digit.

```
# Here, comparison is with strings, not integers. 
s.astype(str).str[0].isin(['5', '7'])

0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7     True
8    False
9     True
Name: Case, dtype: bool
```

Reminder: *much, much, slower*.

Comment: Updated to compare with multiple values at once.

Comment: thanks, i am not as familiar yet with isin.. will review this method in future

Comment: @msulol Can you review it now? I wager it's better than string comparison.

Comment: Sure, i tried the first line of code, but i cant get it to filter, i dont fully understand the syntax yet. here is what i tried, i think i got 100% false. (df["Case #"] // 1e9).astype(int).isin([5, 7])

Comment: @msulol You said 9 digits, perhaps you need `(df["Case #"] // 1e8).astype(int).isin([5, 7])` instead of `1e9`

Comment: weird, its 9 digits including the first one, but this seems to have worked. thanks!! df=df[(df["Case #"] // 1e8).astype(int).isin([7])]

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
df = df[(df["Case #"].astype(str).str.startswith('7')) | (df["Case #"].astype(str).str.startswith('5'))]
```

or

```
df = df[df["Case #"].astype(str).str.contains(r'^7|^5')]
```

Comment: If OP wants to add a check for 5 as the question describes, this needs to be `df[df["Case #"].astype(str).str.startswith('7') | df["Case #"].astype(str).str.startswith('5')]`

Comment: No worries, looks correct now although you should probably factor out the redundant `df["Case #"].astype(str)` calculation (if you so wish).

Comment: Since it is an integer column, it was required

Comment: yes but you are doing it twice when you only need to do it once, if that makes sense . . .

Comment: this worked, didnt know you could chain this way. thanks! df = df[df["Case #"].astype(str).str.contains(r'^7')]

Comment: Works with str.contains but not using str.startswith